# Unable to resolve module `stream`

Tags: npm, react-native

This error starting showing up all of a sudden.

```
Node : v10.16.3
React native : 0.60.5
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

> bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `stream` from `/Users/username/React Native/SampleApp/node_modules/browser-stdout/index.js`: Module `stream` does not exist in the Haste module map

It's giving error for this line :

```
var WritableStream = require('stream').Writable
```

I tried installing 'stream' via npm

```
npm install stream
```

Then other similar errors started showing up.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use the client package [readable-stream](https://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream#readme). If dependencies are requiring `stream`, then i would suggest adding the following to your babel config as well.

`yarn add readable-stream`

`yarn add -D babel-plugin-rewrite-require`

`babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  // rest of config
  plugins: [
    // other plugins
    [
      'babel-plugin-rewrite-require',
      {
        aliases: {
          stream: 'readable-stream',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Answer (score -1):

just install stream using npm install stream and run the project again.